# Which is the best geographical classification?

Tags: user-behavior, search, user-centered-design

Usually in classified advertising websites to catalog ads by area is used the category/subcategory system's. Like this:

Region / province / city / district

It's quite understandable for users, but I think it's not so accurate: some cities are nearest to other region than others city in the same region.

Some websites has implemented maps for drawing search areas or the radius from the user's position, but in small devices is not so practical.

There are other solutions to catalog ads by area, can you suggest some reading?

Comment: Living in a town which borders two countries, I often wished apps would work seamlessly across nations, but that differs a lot with context. If I wanted to buy something on Ebay, for instance, I might want to minimize transport costs: Free shipping can come from any country, really, but usually parcels within the same jurisdiction are the cheapest. Fetching the item yourself from the seller, however, will often be easier if it’s closer to your home, i.e. the country doesn’t matter at all, except maybe for customs and language barriers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably useful to be able to override any automatic location based systems by allowing users to also enter a 'virtual' location (City / Postcode) which moves the search radius centre point.

(Some friends of mine live on the south side of a large estuary - and routinely use a different location on search to force searches to be be only on their side of the water).

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, your concern around using a Google Maps "near me" type of map function is based on how the resulting map would appear on a small device. (I'm assuming it would be okay to use this kind of function to solve your problem so long as users could assign a geographic position as a starting point rather than using their own location.) If this is the case, then I would suggest limiting the map scale represented initially based on the viewport size. Small viewport = less area shown. That way users with "unsmart" phones will still get a map, while users with smart phones can easily scale up or down in the manner required by the OS.